# Why is this Grphql query not returning any data from my WordPress Grphql api using SWR?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, graphql, next.js

I've written a query that returns my WordPress navigation menus using the WordPress graphql plugin and locally on my files I'm using swr, graphql, graphql-request, and next.js. I've tried adding the query on the wp-grphql section of my site and successfully get the navigation menu:

```
query GET_MENU($id: ID!) {
  menu(id: $id, idType: NAME) {
    count
    id
    databaseId
    name
    slug
    menuItems {
      nodes {
        id
        databaseId
        title
        url
        cssClasses
        description
        label
        linkRelationship
        target
        parentId
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This code works well when I query for the id of Navigation within the GraphiQL plugin as below:

```
{
  "id": "Navigation"
}
```

Here are the results in WP:

[image: How data returns inside grapiql wordpress]

Okay so here's the bits that are important for the request I'm making:

```
const { data, error } = useSWR([NAVIGATION_QUERY, "Navigation"], fetcher /* , { initialData: page } */)
console.log('data=::::::::', data, error); // error undefined data is { menu: null }
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, the only thing I can think of is whether or not I must authenticate somehow to get the nav menus? But I assume that would bring up an error not a null menu item...

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change to a WP theme that supported [multiple menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUsEp.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with this as the code works perfectly fine after doing this.  Though I didn't change the theme and simply activated the primary menus. This worked fine.